# Re-execute function not before it's finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a JS-function with hundreds of lines. I need to make sure, the function is not called again before it has finished executing the previous call.

So I tried this:

```
var executing = false;    
function myFunc(){
   //stop executing if it's already executing
   if(executing){
      return false;
   }
   executing = true;
   /* the main function with ajax-calls etc */
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/"+method+action,
      data: "a=1",
      success: function(data){
         //the inner function logic...
         executing = false;
      }
}
```

Does that look false to you? Where is my flaw? Maybe the error is elsewhere in the not posted code, if you think this makes sense. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: The provided snippet "will work" as expected *unless* other code interferes with it. However, some cases to consider: 1. Something else changes `executing` (remember that other events can be triggered before the AJAX call completes). Also `executing` is a useless generic name in any larger scope; 2) What happens when the AJAX call fails?; 3) Queuing? 4) *Fix* the syntax errors (no closing `)` for instance).

Comment: thank you. Nothing else changes "executing". If the ajax-call would fail, there'd be no problem because then the items would not be added (I use this for loading more items in endless scrolling). Queuing? Could you explain this a bit more?

Comment: You might not want to drop the next request - imagine the user is auto-completing something, they type in X (start AJAX call), then XY - you'd want it to eventually show the words refined to XY (xylophone), not just X (xenon). A simple way to handle this trivial example is to cancel outstanding XHR calls - and perhaps use the XHR object as the sentinel (instead of a separate bool).

Comment: I understand - but it's not autocompleting, but for endless scrolling (loading more comments f.e.)

Comment: If the user scrolls *faster* than the responses, what happens? It *may* be preferable to continue fetching more data - depending on what the UX should be like. Also, what if there is an error and success is never called? Now, all future scrolling will fail until the page is reloaded.

Comment: "*Where is my flaw? Maybe the error…*" - What error? Does something not work for you? Please describe your issue.

Comment: He can't scroll further because he has reached end of window - but the second argument is very true. Hmpf :( Problem is, the situation is very complicated: For further loading, I need to get an attribute of the last element (comment) and send that via ajax - if there are multiple requests with the same ID, there will be duplicate comments. But that brings me to the idea, store the last used attribute and only send an ajax if there is another attribute-value?!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `async` option for jquery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) and set it to false to make synchronous requests :

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      async :false,
      url: "/"+method+action,
      data: {a:1},
      success: function(data){
         //the inner function logic...
         executing = false;
      }
```